# How to delete a coupon using api and coupon code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, coupon

In WooCommerce, I created a coupon like this.

```
$coupon_data = [
    'code' => $code,
    'amount' => '15',
];

$wooCommerceMRLiveV2 = WooCommerceConnection::wooCommerceMRLiveV2();
$retval2 = $wooCommerceMRLiveV2->post('coupons', $coupon_data);
```

And when the coupon code is used, I need to delete it manually.
But according to API [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html?php#delete-a-coupon), I can only delete coupons using id. But at the moment when the coupon code is used, I don't know the id.
So, is there any method to delete the coupon using coupon code? **Or can I retrieve id from code**?

Comment: you're using rest api where? is it in wordpress? is WooCommerce with the same website? can you add codes to functions.php at where your WooCommerce is? Basically, I need to know how you plan to remove the coupon.

Comment: Hi, I'm using rest api in Larave. And I found the way.

Answer (score 1):

I could delete the coupon like this. I found it [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html?php#list-all-coupons).

```
$coupon_json = $wooCommerceV2->get('coupons', ['code'=>$coupon_code]);
$coupon_arr = json_decode($coupon_json);
$id = $coupon_arr[0]->id;
$result = $wooCommerceV2->delete('coupons/'.$id);
Log::info($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$coupon_code = '10perdiscount';

$cpn = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);

echo $cpn->get_id();
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code about remove coupon.

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$get_previous_coupon = $order->get_used_coupons();
if (count($get_previous_coupon) > 0 && is_array($get_previous_coupon)) {
    foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $applied_coupon_code ){
        $applied_coupon = $applied_coupon_code;
    }
    $order->remove_coupon( $applied_coupon );
    $code = 1;
    $message = 'Coupon successfully removed';
}else{
    $code = 0;
    $message = 'error'; 
}
```

Thanks